# aws websockets with cdk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I would like to use aws websockets API with python cdk.
I can see, there are functions in the documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_apigatewayv2_alpha/README.html) that it is possible but experimental. Now I want to use these constructs but I cannot import them. My IDE does not recognize them as well.
I installed it after researching the experimental module explicitly [see](https://pypi.org/project/aws-cdk.aws-apigatewayv2-alpha/#websocket-api)
However, I cannot import this or anything related to this alpha module.
Does someone else experience this?

```
from aws_cdk.aws_apigatewayv2_authorizers_alpha import WebSocketLambdaAuthorizer
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Authorizers are in the [`aws-cdk/aws-apigatewayv2-authorizers-alpha` module](https://pypi.org/project/aws-cdk.aws-apigatewayv2-authorizers-alpha), which has to be installed separately from `aws-cdk/aws-apigatewayv2-alpha`:

> `pip install aws-cdk.aws-apigatewayv2-authorizers-alpha`